# How do you deploy a Spring Boot war on Tomcat7?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, gradle

I have a Spring Boot Web MVC application using Gradle which runs fine with bootRun. Gradle has also built the war (with 'gradle war') which I have copied to my Tomcat server's webapps directory and after restarting it has been extracted to a directory. When I check the Tomcat manager I see it there registered but I just have no idea how to actually connect to it with a browser. Locally I would access http://localhost:8080/web/home for my index page. If on the server I try http://localhost:8080/my-war-name or even http://localhost:8080/my-war-name/web/home all I get is a Tomcat 404 page. The base Tomcat and admin pages are working fine.

There is nothing in the logs either. All it says is that it is deploying the web application archive and the server has started.

I have tried looking at various questions on SO and guides but I just cannot find a simple guide which tells you what to do to deploy a Spring web app to Tomcat. Where do I start to look to work out what is happening?

**UPDATE**

As stated in my comment I have switched the JVM to Oracle 1.8 and created the war with gradle bootRepackage. When I copied the war to webapps I get:

```
INFO: Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath: [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jersey.JerseyAutoConfiguration@60cf45c0, my.mvcapp.Application@7f2a62a2, my.mvcapp.config.ServletInitializer@1c71c071]
Sep 02, 2015 1:45:22 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
```

Then when I try to start the app in the Tomcat manager I get:

```
...truncated for brevity...
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tokenStore': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:133)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:531)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:119)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:110)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:69)
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5456)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 27 more
```

**UPDATE 2**

So for fun I tried using Jetty 8 and all I get is the contents of the war listed as a directory.

I undid all the changes made since trying Tomcat 7 and then deployed to Tomcat 8. This loads the application and I get the Spring banner in the output now. However, although my controllers are detected they do not appear to be mapped to URLs. I know the question was about Tomcat 7 so I'll need to open a new question for that. I just can't seem to get anywhere with Tomcat 7.

**Why is this made to be so difficult? All I want is to serve code which works perfectly fine running the embedded server. There must be an idiots guide somewhere.**

Comment: Yes, it is the same as the war name. All the files look to be present.

Comment: I changed the Tomcat JVM to Oracle 1.8 and deployed a new war built with bootRepackage and now the application fails to start with a org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException

Comment: Yeah, just radically changing the entire setup pretty much invalidates the question.

Comment: No, I think the question still stands. Am I doing the right thing? As I said, there are no docs to tell you what to do so I am just trying different things. Obviously it still doesn't work even though running it with bootRun is fine.

Comment: just a try to see if the war has no issue, can you run java -jar <your war file>.war ; for this to work you need to leave the main() method from Application

Comment: @FredericHenri I get 'no main manifest attribute, in my-war-name.war'

Comment: well, are you trying with the war generated from bootRepackage ? this one is not meant to be used with java -jar; can you try with the one generated with war only

Comment: @FredericHenri Yes, I am using the one generated by war I'm afraid.

Comment: Did you follow the [Traditional deployment](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-traditional-deployment) chapter in the official documentation?